# Interpolation and image drawing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, interpolation

In my little project I have a function that returns a list of points coordinates. Like this:

```
    points = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2),...]
```

When I draw it on image, I get points on image but I want continious line. How can I get it? And how to draw interpolated lines on an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw lines, do the following:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw

im = Image.new('RGB',(500,500),(255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.line(points, fill=(255,0,0))
del draw 
im.save('output.jpg')
```

Once you understand the above code you'll be able to use the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122049/drawing-an-anti-aliased-line-with-thepython-imaging-library) to draw antialiased lines.

Comment: Yes, it works but line isn't smooth. I see some pixels. I want to do spline interpolation but  i don't know how do it. :)

Comment: @milssky: I've added a link to several alternatives to how to draw antialiased lines with PIL.