# PIL - How can I add rounded corners to a pasted image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've pasted an image on a background, but I'm currently facing a problem where I don't know how to round the corners of the pasted image. I want to round the image that is kept in the user variable from the script below.

Output: [image: Output Image].
What I want: [image: Expected output]

```py
import io, requests
from PIL import Image

user = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/710929396013334608/720738818667446282/65578836_2994649093913191_1181627229703939865_n.jpg').content)).resize((40, 40))
back = Image.new('RGB', (646, 85), (54, 57, 63))
byteImg = io.BytesIO()
back.save(byteImg, format='PNG', quality=95)
back = Image.open(io.BytesIO(byteImg.getvalue()))
back.paste(user, (15, 23))

back.save('done.png') # Should save to the current directory
```

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/60382952/2836621

Comment: You need to create a mask with rounded-corners and pass it as the `mask=` argument to the `paste()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) method. You can use the `PIL.ImageDraw` module to draw the mask image (i.e. via its `ImageDraw.pieslice()` function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned how to compose images. We were able to create and compose a mask image. `Image.composite` from the `PIL` library. I used the article [Composite two images according to a mask image with Python, Pillow](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-composite/) as a reference.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ims = Image.open('./lena_square.jpg')

blur_radius = 0
offset = 4
back_color = Image.new(ims.mode, ims.size, (0,0,0))
offset = blur_radius * 2 + offset
mask = Image.new("L", ims.size, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((offset, offset, ims.size[0] - offset, ims.size[1] - offset), fill=255)
mask = mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(blur_radius))

ims_round = Image.composite(ims, back_color, mask)
plt.imshow(ims_round)
ims_round.save('./lena_mask.jpg', quality=95)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If there are issues with the masking method, you may need to clarify why it's not working to get an answer.