# IOS corner smoothing in python

Tags: python, ios, python-imaging-library, drawing, rounded-corners

I am working on a project that involves video frame manipulation, and one of the requirements is to add smooth rounded corners to the frames. I did some research on how to add rounded corners to images using PIL or any other image processing library, but all of them produce rough corners that look unprofessional.
Here is the code I tried :-

```py
def add_corners(im, rad):
    circle = Image.new('L', (rad * 2, rad * 2), 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle)
    draw.ellipse((0, 0, rad * 2 - 1, rad * 2 - 1), fill=255)
    alpha = Image.new('L', im.size, 255)
    w, h = im.size
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, 0, rad, rad)), (0, 0))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, rad, rad, rad * 2)), (0, h - rad))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, 0, rad * 2, rad)), (w - rad, 0))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, rad, rad * 2, rad * 2)), (w - rad, h - rad))
    im.putalpha(alpha)
    return im

im = Image.open('sand.png')
im = round_corner_jpg(im, 50)
im.save('sand_corner.png')
```

[image]

and here is the result it produces, as can be seen in the above image, the corners are rough and have this pixelated view on them, they are not smooth just like we can do in figma using IOS corner smoothing:-
[image]

I also saw this question that also had the same requirements, but they didn't show the code for how to implement it :- [Any way to make nice antialiased round corners for images in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828345/any-way-to-make-nice-antialiased-round-corners-for-images-in-python)

I want to make sure that there is no loss in the frame quality when adding the rounded corners and the corners should be smooth and better yet look like the corner smoothing in figma

EDIT:-

```py
out = cv2.VideoWriter('assets/pathToSave.mp4', fourcc, fps, (1920, 1080))

def generate_frame():
        while cap.isOpened():
            code, frame = cap.read()
            if code:
                yield frame
            else:
                print("done")
                break
    
for i, frame in enumerate(generate_frame()):
    # Convert opencv frames into PIL Image
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    im_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
    ss = 4
    alpha = Image.new('L', (im.width*ss, im.height*ss))

    # Draw rounded rectangle and unsupersample
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
    d.rounded_rectangle([0,0,im.width*ss-1,im.height*ss-1],radius=120,fill='white')
    alpha = alpha.resize((alpha.width//ss, alpha.height//ss), 
    resample=Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
    alpha.save('DEBUG-alpha.png')

    # Push new alpha channel into original image and save
    im_pil.putalpha(alpha)
    im_np = np.array(im_pil.convert('RGB'))

    open_cv_image = im_np[:, :, ::-1].copy()

    outputVideo.write(open_cv_image)
```

I tried the above code in order to have rounded corners from an incoming video frames, but I still got rough corners :-

[image]

Please look at the white frame, the transparent rounded corners are a part of background on which this video is rendered upon

Comment: you might wanna check the appearance of the circle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an antialiasing method for Python PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350645/is-there-an-antialiasing-method-for-python-pil)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, What about the ios corner smoothing?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. You are acquiring video as Numpy arrays with OpenCV, then converting to PIL, adding an alpha channel, then removing the alpha channel, then converting back to Numpy array and saving as a video.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes, its because the frame is np array and because I wanted to add rounded corners to the frame using PIL, I had to covert it into a format which PIl can understand

Comment: If you want to add them, why do you remove them again with `im_np = np.array(im_pil.convert('RGB'))`

Comment: And if you want to add them to every frame, why do you re-calculate the alpha in every frame? Surely it isn't going to change through the life of your video, so you can calculate it once before you start acquiring video and then just apply it to every frame.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I had to change them back into a format that opencv and work with, because I had other processes that involves frame manipulation using opencv. I also need PIL in order to add rounded corners to the frame

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is better:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Open image
im = Image.open('rock.jpg')

# Make alpha channel, supersampled by factor 4
ss = 4
alpha = Image.new('L', (im.width*ss, im.height*ss))

# Draw rounded rectangle and unsupersample
d = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
d.rounded_rectangle([0,0,im.width*ss-1,im.height*ss-1],radius=120,fill='white')
alpha = alpha.resize((alpha.width//ss, alpha.height//ss), resample=Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
alpha.save('DEBUG-alpha.png')

# Push new alpha channel into original image and save
im.putalpha(alpha)
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Note that, as the original image was not supplied by OP, I had to cut out centre of his roughly cropped image and resize that up to the original size, so my starting image is already somewhat unsharper than the original as a result.

Comment: I tried the approach you shared, and my goal was to put this logic on editing the video frames to be rounded and this is the result I got :- https://imgur.com/a/EMpt1He
In the image, look at the roughness it produces, the transparent rounded corners are generated through CSS and canvas, but the frame is rounded through PIL

Comment: Your [mcve] contains no code for video creation or CSS, so I don't see any way to assist you.

Comment: I updated the question with what I tried based on your answer

Comment: the "downsample higher-res mask" approach was already mentioned, but not terribly well elaborated, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350645/is-there-an-antialiasing-method-for-python-pil which I referenced in my dupe flag

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution of the many good ones is to use GaussianBlur from PIL import ImageFilter . It would look something like this  =>

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFilter

def convert_jpg_to_png(jpg_path, png_path):
img = Image.open(jpg_path)
img.save(png_path)



def add_corners(im, rad,blur_radius):
circle = Image.new('L', (rad * 2, rad * 2), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle)
draw.ellipse((0, 0, rad * 2 - 1, rad * 2 - 1), fill=255)
alpha = Image.new('L', im.size, 255)
w, h = im.size
#cirlce quadrents 
alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, 0, rad, rad)), (0, 0))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, rad, rad, rad * 2)), (0, h - rad))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, 0, rad * 2, rad)), (w - rad, 0))
alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, rad, rad * 2, rad * 2)), (w - rad, h - rad))

#add blur to just cornors 
for i in range(0, w, w - rad):
    for j in range(0, h, h - rad):
        corner = alpha.crop((i, j, i + rad, j + rad))
        blurred_corner = corner.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(blur_radius))
        alpha.paste(blurred_corner, (i, j))
im.putalpha(alpha)
return im
```

This with this code gave me this=>

```
convert_jpg_to_png('mountain-landscape-2031539_1280.jpg', 'mountain-landscape-2031539_1280.png')
im = Image.open('mountain-landscape-2031539_1280.png')
im = add_corners(im, 500,5)
im.save('mountain-landscape-2031539_1280_corner.png')
```

[A close up of the blurred border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy3RB.png)

This was the image generated from this code :D. ): unfortunately the file size is to large. Ok i will just apply it to your image here=>

```
im = Image.open('Beirp.png')
im = add_corners(im, 50,2)
im.save('new_idk_image.png')
```

This was your image that you rounded the corners with it has blurring applied:

[image: This was your image that you rounded the corners with it has blurring applied]

Gl with the coding :D.